# Modificar un dataframe con dependencias

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe como éste:

```
> print(A)
         5 3 7 6 11 4 20 8 16 18
     r01 1 1 1 1  1 1  1 1  1  0
     r02 0 0 0 0  0 0  0 1  1  0
     r03 1 0 1 0  1 1  0 0  0  0
     r04 0 1 0 0  0 1  0 1  0  1
     r05 1 1 0 1  1 1  0 0  1  1
```

Y otro como éste:

```
    > print(B)
     head_req_ID tail_req_ID
1         r04         r01
2         r01         r02
3         r05         r03
```

Para cada columna de A tengo que comprobar con los datos de B.

B es una estructura que indica los requisitos: nos indica que, para poder tener `1` en `r01`, tiene que estar `r04` a `1`. Es decir,

> siempre tiene que estar el elemento de la primera columna para poder tener el de la segunda columna,

y así para todas las filas de B. Pongo un ejemplo gráfico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDIT**

Probé lo siguiente:

```
checkImp <- function(x,y,z){

  print(c("Columna de A",x))
  print(c("Primer elemento de B",y))
  print(c("Segundo elemeno de B",z))

  print(c("Obtengo el primer índice",indice1 <- which(data$req_ID %in% y)))
  print(c("Obtengo el segundo índice",indice2 <- which(data$req_ID %in% z)))

   if(x[as.numeric(indice1)] == 0 & x[as.numeric(indice2)] != 0){
     x[indice2] <- 0
   }
}

mapply(checkImp,A,B[,1],B[,2])
```

**Print output**

```
[1] "Columna de A" "1"            "0"            "1"            "1"            "1"            "0"            "0"            "1"           
[10] "0"            "1"            "0"            "1"            "0"            "0"            "1"            "0"            "0"           
[19] "0"            "0"            "1" 

[1] "Primer elemento de B" "r04"                 
[1] "Segundo elemento de B" "r01"
```

El problema está en que sólo puedo comparar la columna de A con el primera fila de B, necesito comparar la columna de A con TODOS los datos de B.

Comment: ¿Y qué intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Pobré a hacerlo con apply, pero el problema es que tengo que comparar la columna de A con toda la estructura de datos B. Por lo que la operación por columnas no me vale, no sé cómo lo prodría solucionarlo de otra forma

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta agregando lo que intentaste? Ayudanos a ayudarte. Responder sobre la base de un código ya empezado es mucho más sencillo a la hora de entender en qué se debe enfocar una respuesta y comprender cuáles fueron tus dificultades a la hora de implementarlo

Comment: Editado, a ver si así se entiende mejor, mcuhas gracias.

Comment: `B` tiene solo 3 filas, entiendo que solo aplicarías el algoritmo sobre las tres primeras filas de `A`?

Comment: No, debería aplicarse B para todas las columnas de A, lo he solucionado, pero creo que no es la más óptima, pongo la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Para cada fila de A con el índice que hay en cada fila de B compruebo los valores, obtengo los valores sin modificar en A primeramente, `valor1` compueba para `tail`, si `head` está a 1 `tail` tiene que estar a 0 y de la otra manera para `valor2`. Después escribo en la estructura.

```
checkExc <- function(A){

    for(i in 1:nrow(B)) {

      valor1 <- ifelse((A[B$head_req_ID[i],] == 1) , 0,A[B$tail_req_ID[i],])
      valor2 <- ifelse((A[B$tail_req_ID[i],] == 1) , 0,A[B$head_req_ID[i],])

      A[B$tail_req_ID[i],] <<- valor1
      A[B$head_req_ID[i],] <<- valor2

    }
  }


if(nrow(B)!=0){
  checkExc(A)
}
```